# Microphone doesn't work on remote desktop in Windows Server 2019

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

I have headphones with microphone, model: MICROSOFT LX-3000.

And when I'm connecting with RDP to the server the sound works but the microphone doesn't.

I don't even see it or other input devices in the sound control panel > record tab.

I have tried to set in the RDP option "record on this computer" and it's not working too.

nothing works .

[image: sound control panel]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *Bi-directional sound can be configured in the Windows client on a per-connection basis. The relevant settings can be accessed in the Remote audio section of the Local Resources options tab.* from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-client-faq

Comment: If so then probably the microphone isn't correctly configured or selected in the client.

Comment: @ChanganAuto on the client its selected and working and if the client connecting to rdp with windows 10 its working . but when connecting to the server its doesnt

Comment: https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/rdp-microphone-redirection-not-working-2578.html

Comment: @ChanganAuto i did that too :) not working

Comment: If so it's time for you to update the question by [edit]ing. This avoids being suggested things you already tried. Make sure to describe everything you tried already exactly as it went, including any error messages.